# Unity - Add call back to GameObject OnMouseDown Event

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Currently when I am trying to detect whether an object has been clicked / interacted with by the mouse, I create a script on that GameObject and then define `void OnMouseDown()` and apply functionality within. If I then want to trigger a function in another script that is **not** attached to the GameObject I call it through a `GetComponent<>()` reference.

Is there a way to add a callback to the OnMouseDown event from a script on another GameObject? Potentially in the same way delegates / events are allocated and invoked? Something such as: `gameObjectReference.GetComponent<BoxCollider>().onmousedownevent += MyFunction;` So that it automatically calls this function on mouse down?

**Note:** I know that you can use raycasting to achieve something similar, but my question is about attaching callbacks to the existing Unity event.

Comment: sure, use Unity Events - you've exactly described them.  Just click to the manual or a billion QA or tutorials

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because full information instantly available at the manual https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/intermediate/scripting/events  Also check out http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unityevent-where-have-you-been-all-my-life.321103/

Comment: just BTW if you are touching/inputting, this is like the fundamental, overwhelming problem in unity:  http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/784617/how-do-i-block-touch-events-from-propagating-throu.html

Comment: @JoeBlow So how do I attach it to the pre-exsisting event that triggers OnMouseDown? Because I don't want to have to create additional scripts on objects to trigger such events. The video you linked describes how to craete an event / delegate system, I don't want to create a new one, I want to attach a callback to a pre-exsisting unity event trigger for that object, and that is what I don't understand..?

Comment: inside the relevant OnMouseDown, just more.Invoke, and drag anything you want to `more` which is a `public UnityEvent`.  it's "less than" one line of code, you just drag.

Comment: @JoeBlow Maybe I haven't explained myself clearly enough, which I apologize for, I want to skip the part where I have to define OnMouseDown. i.e. that script won't exist, I just want to capture the event that would trigger that. So,,,, 2 GO's (GameObjects), 1 Script on GO1. GO1 script detects onmousedown on GO2. Thoughts?

Comment: Are you saying you have a call called say `MyFunction()`. You want it to behave exactly as `OnMouseDown()` does. is that it?

Comment: have you checked out `OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)` (my 3rd link above has some examples of that, to get started)

Comment: @JoeBlow Yes, except `MyFunction()` is not attached to the GameObject that is triggering it, unlike `OnMouseDown()` which must be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) I understand the sense of what you mean by this

```
pseudocode:
gameObjectReference.GetComponent<BoxCollider>().onmousedownevent += MyFunction
```

and there is no way to do that.

2) please do understand: it is *incredibly easy* to achieve your aim (elegantly). Add a UnityEvent in script "b", Invoke it in the OnMouseDown. drag anything you want there.  For anyone reading who is new to Unity, pls try `UnityEvent` in general as it is used constantly

3) A I mention you can *kind of* do what you want by fooling around with the `OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)` systems, but this just emphasises you can't do what you ask, do it with OnMouseDown.

Sorry for the grim news.

Comment: No worries, thanks for the comments and final answer. :)