# How to make text appear in an onmousedown collision for C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I am going to write a script that allows to show some text  when you click on a chest, Should I use an `OnMouseDown` or `OnCollisionEnter`? in which case, I would want to find the collision of the chest when you click on it. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect click/touch events on UI and GameObjects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41392130/1092820)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unity - Add call back to GameObject OnMouseDown Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35352225/unity-add-call-back-to-gameobject-onmousedown-event)

Comment: Yes thanks :) the correct answer would be OnMouseDown.

Comment: @Sprky12 Actually, `OnPointerDown` would be better, since it works with more than just mouse input, which includes being more performant for mobile, and allows you to have finer control over what blocks or does not block the click. See [How to detect click/touch events on UI and GameObjects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41392130/1092820)

Answer (score 0):

OnCollisionEnter don't make any sense in this context. Just use OnMouseDown and show a UI text object. Add anytype collider to the chest and check IsTrigger Property of chest(If your game dont need to interact wit it physically). Then add component with OnMouseDown function and use necessary script to show UI Text object.